# How to check whether a variable consists of a number and a letter (eg: 3a)

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to read a excel file and I identify the rows I need based on the row number.
Unfortunatly the rows are like this:

- 1: Topic 2
- 1a: important info...
- 1b: important info...
- 2: Topic 2
- 2a: important info...

So what I do is, I check each row with a for-loop and then I have if-statement where only the topics with 1a,1b,2a, ... , 29c should pass.

```
for($i=19 ; $i<173 ; $i++){
            "code"
            if( ??? )){
                "code";
            }
        }
```

Do you have any idea how to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
if(preg_match('\d+\D', 'Your_Input') === 1){
    //doStuff();
}
```

You might have to play around with the actual expression a bit, since there may be slight differences between various languages, but `\d+\D` should basically work, at least [it does for me](https://regex101.com/r/ST8WWU/2).

Also, here's some more information about [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```php
for($i=19 ; $i<173 ; $i++){
    "code"
    if (preg_match("/\d+[a-z]/", $rowNumber)) {
        "code";
    }
}
```

`\d+[a-z]` matches any sequence of digits (`\d+`) followed by a letter (`[a-z]`).
The variable `$rowNumber` needs to be replaced by the variable that actually contains the row number in your code.